# Multiple search queries at once?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

When searching through the primary search bar, the query is made off of the entire string (e.g. Searching "Hello world!" takes the string at face value). Is there a way of "splitting" the query to search for two things at once (e.g. Searching "Hello|world!" takes two strings into query; "Hello" & "world!")? If something like this isn't added, it would be an excellent feature.

Comment: How about "Hello" "World"?  Here is a sample search for "Hello" "Module": http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hello%22+%22module%22

Comment: I think that the search takes hello world, tokenizes it into each term, i.e. term[0] = hello, term[1] = world, and then it filters based on that criteria. A better example would be to search for hello golf in which case you can see that the two terms are anded together.